# Why isn't my FTP server saving files properly?

Tags: ftp, notepad++, filezilla

I'm using Notepad++ with it's FTP functionality to edit files on my local machine. I also have FileZilla server running on my local machine which I am connecting to. I know this is a strange way of doing things, but it works for me (or it did) as I often modify files that are not local.

A few weeks ago, something strange started happening. When I save files, it appears that it doesn't save the file completely, i.e. at some point in the file, it's stops saving and I only get half the file.

I've reinstalled the Notepad++ plugin and I've updated to the latest version of FileZilla server, but to no avail. Concerned it might be the hard drive failing, I set up another directory (in Filezilla server) on a different hard drive, but it keep happening.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you use the FileZilla client (or another FTP client) can you upload new files successfully?

Comment: Sorry, misread the question

Comment: @techie, I've just tried a few files, and they seem absolutely fine.

Comment: It appears this is only occurring when saving CSS files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe cache folder of Notepad NppFTP is damaged. Use disk check. Also try SynWrite app-- it has ported NppFTP with name SynFTP. Does it show same?

Answer (score 0):

I was same problem, but today I fix it. Install this version [notepad++ v7.3.3](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v7.3.3.html) - it fix your problem.

Comment: Just curious, why not install the latest version?